# Bracket Bottom type and how to remove it?

Tags: bottom-bracket

I can't seem to find what kind of bottom bracket I have on my bike and how to remove it to put some grease on/in it. My bike is a Schwinn Cadence 2006 mountain bike.
[image]

Right side (crankset side) above
[image]
Left side above (with a bit of threading)

Any help would be very much appreciated ! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a standard British bottom bracket with a fixed cup and adjustable cup.

[This article](https://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/bottom-bracket-service-adjustable-cup-and-cone) gives a good overview of how to service. It looks like your lockring is missing. Also, it doesn't look like you'll be able to use a pin spanner on the adjustable cup. Not clear from the photo what kind of wrenching affordance the cup has, but it should have some kind of wrench flats, so possibly [this kind of tool](https://www.parktool.com/product/adjustable-cup-wrench-hcw-11?category=Crank%20%26%20Bottom%20Bracket) is what you need. Also note that the fixed cup can be extremely difficult to remove.

Comment: Thanks ! Exactly what I was looking for ! :)

Comment: Additionally, if there is damage inside, consider replacing with a sealed BB cartridge.  They're "sealed for life" and adjustment-free, so that makes riding better.

Comment: There should also be a left-hand threaded lockring in the second photo, which appears to be missing.  That could be a reason for the bearing adjustment to have moved over time.

Comment: @Criggie The non-drive side of both BSA and ITA threaded BB cups is regular, including the lock-ring. Only the drive side of BSA is left-handed.

Comment: @LamarLatrell fair point, I errored on the thread handedness.  There is a lockring missing from the left side which could be the reason bearing adjustment has changes over time.

Comment: I still have the lockring. I had removed it for the photo but forgot to mention it. Thank you all for the additionnal infos.